# C how to combine string hash function with boolean?

Tags: c, algorithm, hash, hashcode

I have a struct which contains a char* and a char which is always either 1 or 0.  Here is my struct definition:

```
typedef struct Literal {
    char *name;
    char is_negated;
} Literal;
```

For string hashing I am using djb2 from http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html:

```
size_t str_hash(void *string) {
    unsigned char *str = string;
    size_t hash = 5381;
    int c;
    while ((c = *str++)) {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
    }
    return hash;
}
```

I need to create a hash for my struct which will combine the information from the string hash with `is_negated`.

Comment: `I have a struct` - yet your function takes `void *string`? why `void*`?? `a boolean (char)` `char` is not a `_Bool`. But code speaks 1000 words - post the structure definition, rather then explain with it contains. `struct { char *string; _Bool c; }` is more clear what the struct is. `will combine the information` How do you want to "combine" this information? What does it mean?

Comment: why not simply treat the bool as another character in your string. If `b` is your bool (that takes values 0 or 1), and `hash` is your string hash, you can calculate `(hash * 33) + b`.

Comment: I've now included the struct definition in the question. The reason that the hash function takes `void *string` is because I'm passing it in to a hash table I've written which needs to take a hash function for `void*` since the hash table could contain any type.  `(hash * 33) + b` would bias the result toward multiples of 33.  I normalise the hash function with `%` in my hash table so this would bias the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do it without introducing a bias:

```
return (str_hash(name) << 1) + is_negated;
```